# Scheduling Query by using Script

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'd like to ask if it's possible or not to rum query scheduling by using script?

As for creating table, we could use script

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.xxx AS

...
```

Is there any way to do this but to CREATE A SCHEDULER instead of clicking the 'Schedule Query' Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query), in order to schedule a query , you can use one of the following methods:

1. BigQuery console and click "Schedule Query" as you mentioned in your question.
2. `bq` command
3. Python API

I will share same examples with you, first using `bq` command. From the Cloud Shell environment you can execute the following command:

```
bq query \
    --use_legacy_sql=false \
    --destination_table=mydataset.mytable \
    --display_name='My Scheduled Query' \
    --replace=true \
    'SELECT
      1
FROM
     mydataset.test'
```

In addition, using ***bq command*** you can also use other flags, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query).

Second, using the Python API, you can configure your schedule query using the `DataTransferServiceClient`, which allows you to pass all the query configuration through a json dictionary, such as this example in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#python) and below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1
import google.protobuf.json_format

client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()

# TODO(developer): Set the project_id to the project that contains the
#                  destination dataset.
# project_id = "your-project-id"

# TODO(developer): Set the destination dataset. The authorized user must
#                  have owner permissions on the dataset.
# dataset_id = "your_dataset_id"

# TODO(developer): The first time you run this sample, set the
# authorization code to a value from the URL:
# https://www.gstatic.com/bigquerydatatransfer/oauthz/auth?client_id=433065040935-hav5fqnc9p9cht3rqneus9115ias2kn1.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
#
# authorization_code = "_4/ABCD-EFGHIJKLMNOP-QRSTUVWXYZ"
#
# You can use an empty string for authorization_code in subsequent runs of
# this code sample with the same credentials.
#
# authorization_code = ""

# Use standard SQL syntax for the query.
query_string = """
SELECT
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as current_time,
  @run_time as intended_run_time,
  @run_date as intended_run_date,
  17 as some_integer
"""

parent = client.project_path(project_id)

transfer_config = google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict(
    {
        "destination_dataset_id": dataset_id,
        "display_name": "Your Scheduled Query Name",
        "data_source_id": "scheduled_query",
        "params": {
            "query": query_string,
            "destination_table_name_template": "your_table_{run_date}",
            "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "partitioning_field": "",
        },
        "schedule": "every 24 hours",
    },
    bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.TransferConfig(),
)

response = client.create_transfer_config(
    parent, transfer_config, authorization_code=authorization_code
)

print("Created scheduled query '{}'".format(response.name))
```